# AVX Search Array UB with zero input

Tags: c, avx512

I'm trying to search an array with AVX:

```
 __attribute__((target("avx512bw"))) int search(int* nums, int numsSize, int target) {
   // align nums 
   int arr[16] __attribute__((aligned(512)));
   __builtin_memcpy(arr, nums, numsSize*sizeof(int));
   // build vectors
   const __m512i valueVec = _mm512_set1_epi32(target);
   const __m512i searchVec = _mm512_load_epi32(&arr[0]);    
   // compare
   const __mmask16 equalBits = _mm512_cmpeq_epi32_mask(searchVec, valueVec);
   return equalBits;
}
```

When I have a `0` in the input for `nums`, like `[0,1,3,5,9,12]`, and `target=0`, I get wrong results that are close to high powers of 2: `33282`, `33281`, `2692`.

Is this due to the undefined bits in `searchVec`? Like it matches on the first zero of the ones not filled because my input does not fill the vector completely?

Also is there a way to convert the `equalBits` bitmask, which is 1,2,4,8,16, to the vector's index of the matching value, like 1,2,3,4,5? I tried `_tzcnt_u32( (unsigned int) equalBits)` but it looks like it needs to be cast to a vector, `unsigned int __X`.

Comment: Copying your data to an aligned buffer just so you can load it once with `_mm512_load_epi32` instead of `_mm512_loadu_epi32` is a huge waste.  How do you think memcpy works internally?  It's already going to have your data in vector registers, if the compiler doesn't optimize away the copy.  Also, for style and clarity use `_mm512_loadu_si512` - you're not masking the load, it doesn't need an element size.  Also, you're not using any AVX512BW features here; you're searching 32-bit `int` dword elements.

Comment: `33282` is `0x8202`, so you had a match in the highest element.  Are you sure your input had 16 elements?   You're copying `numsSize` elements, but then unconditionally loading and comparing 16, so you might be comparing uninitialized garbage from `alignas(64) int arr[16]` if you didn't copy 16.  Or if you copied more than 16 ints, you might be seeing weirdness from the UB of writing past the end of `arr`.  Again, don't use `arr[]`.

Comment: I had to change my avx target to get the unassigned load functions. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to mask off the unused elements.

```cpp
int search(int* nums, int numsSize, int target) {
   // mask unused values -- assumes numsSize is <= 15
   auto const mask = (1 << numsSize) - 1;
   // build vectors
   const __m512i valueVec = _mm512_set1_epi32(target);
   const __m512i searchVec = _mm512_maskz_loadu_epi32(mask, nums);
   // compare
   const __mmask16 equalBits = _mm512_mask_cmpeq_epi32_mask(mask, searchVec, valueVec);
   return equalBits;
}
```

You don't need to copy to an aligned temporary array; you can use the `loadu` (for "unaligned") intrinsics.

---

> is there a way to convert the equalBits bitmask, which is 1,2,4,8,16, to the vector's index of the matching value, like 1,2,3,4,5?

If you have more than one match, easy way is to make a vector of indices, then compress it

```cpp
auto const indices = _mm512_set_epi32(15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0);
// Assuming exactly one match, store to an array or something otherwise:
int index;
_mm512_mask_compressstoreu_epi32(&index, k, indices);
// See also _mm512_maskz_compress_epi32 to return a zmm instead of storing to a ptr:
// int index = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(
//          _mm256_castsi256_si128(
//            _mm512_castsi512_si256(matchedIndices)));
```

If you're doing this in a loop, use `_mm512_set1_epi32(16)` and add that to `indices` in each iteration.

If you have exactly one match, then you're correct about `tzcnt` and just need to cast the mask to an int:

```cpp
_tzcnt_u32(static_cast<uint32_t>(k))
```

Comment: In practice `__mmask16` is just a typedef for `unsigned short`.  But if you want to be pedantic about how Intel documents things, there's `unsigned int _cvtmask16_u32(__mmask16)` as an intrinsic for `kmovw`.  Actual code-gen will be identical at least with GCC / clang, it's almost certainly just defined to return its arg so implicit conversion does its thing.  Otherwise I'd recommend just treating it as an integer type and let implicit conversion happen, especially with `_tzcnt_u32` and `_lzcnt_u32` which specify the exact width of their inputs.

Comment: That worked, thank you. I had to use `__builtin_ctz` instead of `tzcnt`. `static_cast` was undefined, and C style cast to `unsigned int` did not compile.

Comment: @steve76: What compiler are you using?  You mentioned in comments under the question having to compile with different target options; if you forgot to compile with `-march=native` or `-march=haswell` or something that would imply BMI1 and thus tzcnt, `__attribute__((target("avx512bw")))` doesn't imply it, so yeah GCC or clang won't let you use intrinsics for instruction sets you didn't tell it were usable.  (`-march=haswell` could make sense as a non-AVX512 baseline if you do runtime dispatch for some functions.  But this one's so short you should be letting it inline into a loop.)

Comment: gcc 8.2. It's an online IDE where I can't change the compilation settings.